# Magento How to disable Redis Caching at run time if REDIS server failover

Tags: magento, redis

We've had an Redis downtime:
`Can't save in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory`
and our web didn't work for a while.
I would like to to set Magento properly  to fallback into disk file cache if Redis is out. What's the best option?
We're runnig Magento 1.9.3.2 and Redis 3.2.10, our app/etc/local.xml cache and session settings are:

```
<cache>
  <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
  <backend_options>
  <server>127.0.0.1</server>
  <port>6379</port>
  <persistent></persistent>
  <database>12</database>
  <password></password>
  <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
  <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
  <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
  <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
  <compress_data>1</compress_data>
  <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
  <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
  <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
  <use_lua>0</use_lua>
  </backend_options>
</cache>

<session_save>db</session_save>
<redis_session>
  <host>127.0.0.1</host>
  <port>6379</port>
  <password></password>
  <timeout>2.5</timeout>
  <persistent></persistent>
  <db>13</db>
  <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
  <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
  <log_level>1</log_level>
  <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
  <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
  <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
  <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>
  <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
  <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
  <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
  <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
  <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
</redis_session>
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it the correct way you should consider to assign more memory to redis. Also split your cache and session into two different redis processes running on different ports. Magento cache does not need persistent caching however a lot of memory for all the keys. Also review Eviction policies in your redis config. https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

If you still interested on a dirty fall-back you could patch the Mage_Core_Model_App

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php

```
 $this->_cache = Mage::getModel('core/cache', $options);

+        if ($this->_cache) {
+                try {
+                        $this->_cache->load('somekey');
+                } catch (Exception $e) {
+                        Mage::getConfig()->setNode('global/cache/backend', 'file');
+                        return $this->getCache();
+                }
+        }
```

in method _initCache